# Can anyone help identify this soldier's uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, uniform

[image]The only info I have about this photograph is that it was taken in WW1. The badges were a bit too grainy for me to match them up with others that I am familiar with so hoping someone else with more knowledge can assist! Asking on behalf of a friend. Thank you!

Comment: Looks to be Austro Hungarian to me, with a "Jaeger" style slouch hat.  I think I can make out the Edelweiss badge on the collars.

Comment: The belt buckle seems to be British or at least commonwealth, although the hat is nothing I've seen on a British uniform before. I'd have gone with Italian Alpini if not for the belt buckle.

Comment: What country is the friend from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a uniform of the [New Zealand Mounted Rifles Brigade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_Mounted_Rifles_Brigade), the [slouch hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slouch_hat#New_Zealand) in particular looks nearly identical.

Formed in 1914 by the combination of three mounted regiments and disbanded in 1919, the brigade served in the [Gallipoli Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallipoli_Campaign) and the [Sinai and Palestine Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinai_and_Palestine_Campaign). The photo looks like it could have been taken in the dry scrubland near [the beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANZAC_Cove) where the Australian and New Zealand troops landed.

Plenty of more detailed info on them can be found [here](http://www.nzmr.org/kit.htm).

[image: Black and white photograph of Harry Bonnington of the New Zealand Mounted Rifles, in uniform]

[image: Colored photograph of Sinclair Chapman Reid of the New Zealand Mounted Rifles, in uniform]

Comment: We live in New Zealand so this certainly seems to be the most likely answer. Thank you very much for your time and information!